# Playing consecutive externally loaded swfs

Tags: actionscript-3, animation, flash, external, playback

I'm trying to load external swf files and, using as3, have them play consecutively so the final product is a seamless animation. Below is the scripting I'm currently using to call and play the first scene, how do I make it go to the next one?

All the material I've found on this is related to buttons and I'm not experienced enough with AS3 to adapt that to what I'm trying to do here.

Here is the script I'm currently using...

```
var Xpos:Number = 0;
var Ypos:Number = 0;
var swf:MovieClip;
var loader:Loader = new Loader();

var sceneOne:URLRequest = new URLRequest("swfs/titlecard2.swf");

loader.load(sceneOne);
loader.x = Xpos;
loader.y = Ypos;
addChild(loader);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You'll want to add an event to the end of each SWF that you are loading to signify that its animation is complete. You'll use that event to trigger the switch between them.
2. You should also have each SWF pause at first by default so you can trigger its start from the parent.
3. I'd load all of the SWFs in the beginning, then begin playback when they are complete. For a good loader, try [LoaderMax](http://www.greensock.com/loadermax/) from GreenSock. It's very simple to use and performs well.